# Неправильная кодировка при выводе русских литер в консоль (������) и получение properties из pom.xml java-методом

Tags: java, кодировка, intellij-idea, maven, cucumber

Проект работал, потом не знаю после чего но кодировки сломались... настроены как надо по всевозможным рекомендациям которые выдаёт гугл при поиске "настройка кодировок IDEA/Windows10". Больше скажу, после смены кодировок в настройке IDEA на utf8 проект вообще перестал работать, даже каракуль не стало) фича стала просто `undefined`

- настраивал кодировки Windows 10;
- настраивал кодировки IDEA;
- настраивал кодировки в `pom.xml`-файле;
- руками менял кодировки каждого файла в проекте (не ну а вдруг помогло бы?)

На чужом ПК всё настроено аналогичным образом и отображает русские литеры что при Run через Maven, что через Cucumber `.feature`-файл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После подробного сравнения своего проекта с другим обнаружил строки кода благодаря которым всё стало работать положенным образом.

В файле `pom.xml` в `<build> <plugins> ...` добавил следующей плагин:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
</plugin>
```

И никаких ������.

Помимо этого необходимо указать настройки idea следующим образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В случае если вам необходимо получать параметры `<properties>` из `pom.xml`, через некоторый `config.properties` в котором этот параметр указан в `${*}`, то необходимо будет считывать данные из `config.properties`, который дублируется в `target/` и если значение `properties` на русском, то будет необходимо применить метод вроде этого:

```
public String encodeToUTF8(String stringToEncode) {
    byte[] stringBytes = stringToEncode.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
    return new String(stringBytes, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
}
```