# Вместо русских букв знаки вопроса(но не обычные) � в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Всем привет, не могу решить проблему с кодировкой. При выводе русских букв в консоли Intellij Idea выходят знаки вопроса ��� вместо каждой буквы.Везде где мог вроде поставил кодировку UTF-8. Как сделать нормальный вывод русских букв?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Неправильная кодировка при выводе русских литер в консоль (������) и получение properties из pom.xml java-методом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/895581/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-p)

Answer (score -1):

В Intellij Idea заходим Help > Edit Custom VM Options добавляем в конец:

```
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Второй вариант установить JDK 17.

Comment: Пробовал, то же самое. Сделать это можно только установив jdk 17?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте изменить кодировку в среде разработки на `ANSI`. `ANSI` поддерживает как и русские, так и английские символы. Если не ошибаюсь, то сделать это можно так: `File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Encoding` .

Comment: Мой ответ неверен?